# write_videofile taking too much time (stuck) sometimes moviepy python

Tags: python, video, azure-functions, video-processing, moviepy

I am writing video after concatenating different clips using moviepy. On writing that video file it takes too much time to write that and sometimes it stuck on writing.

[image]

I have also used options like threads, bitrate, fps, logger but still facing this issue. Video length can be 15 minutes. But it should not take more than 1 hour. I am using Azure App Service Plan with 16 gb memory and 4 vCPU. How can I handle this issue? Is there any best alternative for this?

Answer (score 0):

- One of the workarounds is to pass the parameter `progress_bar = False` to the write_videofile(), Because the progress bar printing every time refreshes IDLE which uses a lot of memory results in decelerating your program until it crashes.
- Making `progress_bar = False` prevents the bar from being written to the shell and improves performance on the system.

**REFERENCES:**
[write_videofile function get slower and slower](https://github.com/Zulko/moviepy/issues/645)

Comment: I am already using Logger=None parameter which is alternative of progress_bar for latest version.